# SharePoint 2010 multi-lingual search refinments

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

I have a search refinement panel in my SharePoint 2010 site that utilizes a managed metadata term set in which I have a second language installed and parallel terms defined for that language.  For example, my multi-lingual term set is "color", and I have "red" and "blue" as my terms, with parallel terms of "rojo" and "azul".

A user can select a the language they want to display with the site, but for some reason I cannot get the Spanish terms to be displayed...the refinement panel always shows the English terms.  My backup plan is to write a custom refinement panel to query the term store and get my alternate language terms, but I would think I could do this through configuration.  Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805062.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/de2d48f6-043f-4dde-a3c3-bd5228c68965